# How do I save changes in online html

Tags: javascript, html, savechanges

What I am trying to do in the code below is to change the text in the Div1 tag with the information in the text input. The thing I want to accomplish is that the text is saved when I reload/quit the page or immediately when it is changed. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="Div1">
    <p>Hi</p>
</div>

<input type="text" id='Input'/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="GetInput();" />



<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetInput () {
        var Input = document.getElementById("Input").value; 
        document.getElementById('Div1').innerHTML= (Input);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between server-side and client-side. However, you could accomplish something like this via `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a client-side language. This means that the page elements (collectively known as the DOM) are only altered after the page is loaded from the web server and rendered in your browser. Javascript can change these but can not save any data.

In order to save data (persistence), you will need some type of data store. This is usually accomplished with a database running on a server. You will need to get your hands on one or possibly rent some storage space.

Comment: depending on the use case, you can also use localStorage as Nick pointed out above.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, it may help you.**

Save value:

`localStorage.setItem("name", $('#Input').val());`

Get value:

`localStorage.getItem("name");`